Fantasy manhwa about a female lead falling in love with the demon king instead of the male lead
It about how the female lead suddenly realizes that she is the lead in a novel and wants to escape her fate, but when she tries to the god of the world helps the male lead try to win her back. The female lead eventually ends up asking the demon king for help and he says yes.
After a while the female lead leads how to use holy power and is actually a saint. The demon king and female lead also fall in love with each other.
The male lead tries to kill the demon king but loses in the end. Then the female lead has to fight god, just so she can have a happy ending with the demon king.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.   When and where did you read this?  Was it in full colour or black-and-white?

It was full color and about two years ago. I don’t remember what website it was on.

Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

It was blond and she had blue eyes.

Do you have a rough sense of how many chapter there were in the manhwa when you read it, or how many you read?

Was she aware that this guy was the demon king, or did she just turn to someone for help and discovered later that he was actually the villain of the novel?

She was not aware that he was the demon king.

Probably around 70-80 chapters but I don’t know if the author ever updated it.

The manhaw was “I’m the Ex-Girlfriend of a Soldier”

Hey, it's great that you figured it out; please don't forget to return in 2 days to accept this answer.  Note that you'll earn more reputation if you add a few more details to this answer: maybe a link to a source, or a quoted summary.
